# Usage problem with my iPad Air

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an iPad Air and I want to update this game that needs 1.4 GB. I only have 5 apps on my iPad and when I go to Settings to look at my storage it says I have used 11 GB. I added up the usage for all my apps and I counted only 3.3 GB. I don't know how to fix this, I've restarted my iPad but it didn't work. I don't know where the other 8 GB is coming from. I also have the same problem on my iPhone 4s.

Comment: Are you running an old iOS perhaps?  Settings > General > storage and iCloud usage > Manage Storage is pretty detailed about usage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I have updated my iPad to the latest IOS update. I also restarted my iPad again and now it sais I have 1.9Gb available. So it went up

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't got any movies, podcasts, music, etc. that is installed on your iPad? Definitely want to check that. iOS uses about 1.8GB of space.

Comment: Often people don't realize they're syncing their photos between iCloud/Dropbox/Amazon/etc. and their iDevice.  Maybe you have a lot of photos?

Answer (score -1):

First, you should update your iPad to the latest iOS system and then if it still takes up you much space, I guess maybe there is much junk files or "other" storage on your iPad Air. You should know what is the Other storage clearly firstly. There are just too many things that require physical storage. That's why Apple chose to lump a lot of things into the "Other" category. Also you can refer to this thread who has the similar situation with you. Hope it's helpful to you. https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/3elqfe/iphone_6_says_storage_almost_fullexcept_its_not/